What is the role of AlCl3 in dealkylation of phenol ring substituted with tertiary butyl?
I was going through the dealkylation reaction of the benzene ring substituted with tertiary butyl and was wondering what is the role of AlCl3 in this?
Here are the details -
During electrophilic addition reaction of benzene derivatives (for example phenol), If I use CH3Cl/AlCl3 reagent, I get para substitution.

To get ortho substitution we do alkylation with tertiary butyl which effectively block the para position and on subsequent reaction with CH3Cl/AlCl3 gives as addition of CH3 at para position.

Now next step is to remove tertiary butyl group from the benzene ring which is the dealkylation process. For this we're using a Benzene + AlCl3 as reagent.
I was wondering what is the role of AlCl3 in the dealkylation process?

You may want to look at this. You usually also do this reverse Friedel-Crafts reaction under acidic (HCl specifically) conditions.

$\ce{AlCl3}$ is a strong Lewis acid that can coordinate with the $\pi$-electrons of the benzene ring, activating it towards electrophilic reactions. Alternatively, $\ce{AlCl3}$ can interact with the tertiary butyl group, destabilizing the carbon-benzene bond by drawing electron density away from the bond.
The tertiary butyl group is prone to cleavage because it forms a very stable tert-butyl carbocation ($\ce{C(CH3)+3}$) when the bond between the benzene ring and the alkyl group breaks. The formation of this stable carbocation is a key driving force for the dealkylation. Once the tertiary butyl group is removed as a carbocation, the benzene ring is regenerated.
Hence, that's why $\ce{AlCl3}$ is used in the dealkylation process.
Hope this helps.
